# Error Code 80070569 configuring Windows DCOM Identity with domain user

Tags: windows, networking, com, privileges

I have a COM application instantiated by a local Windows service with which I would like to gain access to a network share.  To achieve this, I simply attempted to configure my COM server to run as a domain user with access to that share:  I go to the 'dcomcnfg' console, locate my server under Console Root\Component Services\DCOM Config, right-click to 'Properties', go to the 'Identity' tab and specify the domain user for the "This user" option.  When I do this on my own company network, it works beautifully.  However, when a user tries it on their network, they get:

"Catalog Error

An error occurred while processing the last operation on the remote computer 'DOMAIN'.
Error code 80070569 - Logon failure: the user has not been granted the requested logon type at this computer."

where 'DOMAIN' is the name of the customer's domain.  I'm presuming then that this is a problem with their domain policies, but network administration is not my area of expertise.  Anybody have some idea what the problem might be so I can have a clue when I talk to their IT?  Also, if anybody has an alternative approach, I'm open to suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: I would assume the error message means what it says - the domain user lacks the necessary logon right, perhaps "access this computer from the network" (the others are "allow log on locally", "allow log on through remote desktop service", "log on as a batch job" and "log on as a service").  I'm not sure whether it would be the rights on the local system or on the domain controllers that matters here.  You might want to experiment with these settings in your own environment to see if you can reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm pretty sure its the user's rights on the domain, not the local system that's the problem.  The domain user is in the 'Administrators' group on the local PC.  I even compared the local security policies for the user pc to my own and couldn't see any significant difference.  Not sure what permissions look like on a domain controller.  I've never configured one. Unfortunately, I can't access my company domain controller, and I'd hate to have to build a domain controller just to experiment with.

Comment: FWIW, it seems most likely to be the user's logon rights (specifically, "Access this computer from the network") on whichever server is serving out the share, regardless of whether that's a domain controller or a member server.